# MATLAB: dealing with java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, matlab

I seem to be stuck in Kafka-land, with a java.lang.String that I can't seem to use in MATLAB functions:

```
K>> name

name =

Jason

K>> sprintf('%s', name)
??? Error using ==> sprintf
Function is not defined for 'java.lang.String' inputs.

K>> ['my name is ' name]
??? Error using ==> horzcat
The following error occurred converting from char to opaque:
Error using ==> horzcat
Undefined function or method 'opaque' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

how can I get a java.lang.String to convert to a regular MATLAB character array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Matlab doesn't know how to work with anything but it's own structures.

Convert the string to a char:

`cName = char(name);`

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to using `char()` you can also use the java string methods. So

```
cName = name.toCharArray()'
```

Will return a MATLAB character array.

Answer (score 4):

never mind, I figured it out, you have to use the `char()` method explicitly:

```
K>> ['my name is ' char(name)]

ans =

my name is Jason
```

Answer (score 0):

`str2mat(name)` worked for me.